# My database outputs: Resource id #3 in odbc

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I have a database connected to a PHP webpage. I want it to output the "department" a selected "user" is "working". I have the following code to do so:

```
$con=odbc_connect("databaseIuse","", "");
$sql=("SELECT department FROM userdata WHERE username='".$name."'");
$result = odbc_exec($con, $sql);
 echo $result. "<br>";
```

but all I get is:

Resource id #3

I googled for some time for questions with the same problem but all I found was problems with a MySQL database. Those options don't work for me
I am still a beginner in PHP let alone databases. Also, English is not my foreign language so i'm sorry if I am not entirely clear but I do my best.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo $result` which does just that.

Comment: @Jorian Koning print_r(odbc_fetch_row($result)) then check.

Comment: @Sourabh I had actually tried that before but it outputs: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Resource id #3` message you're seeing is the resource result from the query; it is not an error.

You need to loop over (successful) results instead and echo those, not the result's resource.

Here is an example taken from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php

```
$Conn = odbc_connect
("bbdd_usuaris","","",SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC );

$result=odbc_exec($Conn,"select nom from usuaris;");

while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
         for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($result);$i++){
        echo "Result is ".odbc_result($result,$i);
    }
}
```

Consult the main area on PHP.net:

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php

Note: Make sure that `$name` does hold value; that has been left out of the question and its origin is unknown.